# Physics of ice around: Breaking the Ice

Tags: condensed-matter, everyday-life, ice

I was removing ice on my driveway and had a very hard time.

And I am wondering what are the factors that determines the hardness of ice, and also the stickiness.
one thing that I noticed about the thickness of ice is that it does not necessarily  determines its stickiness. There is super thick but super sticky ice.
More importantly what are the lessons I can learn to ease ice removing.

Comment: Ice is strange stuff indeed.  There are many forms; hardness to some extent follows temperature.  Ease of removal usually occurs when the ground is warm enough that there's some liquid water between the ground and the ice sheet.   "Stickiness" depends on all those, as well as the smoothness and material types in your driveway.

Comment: right, it's a concrete driveway, aside from temperature, would pressure or even radiation can play some role in the middle? and the temperature might not necessarily have a linear correlation with the hardness of the ice. it would be interesting to develop a system that we optimize given end users' condition.

Comment: Well, to be blunt, the best method of ice removal is not to allow it to form!  If there's a drain path across your driveway, see if it can be diverted, or even install a French Drain (with metal grating) into the driveway.  After it snows, plow/shovel until it's as close to bare as possible.

Comment: efficient ice removal should have a high impact in general though, like removing ice from space or removing ice for ships? proper physics should be put into study the process.